# Error with app using Flutter - The following assertion was thrown building Answer(dirty): setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build

Tags: flutter, dart

## I'm trying to create a app with flutter, but when i try to run the app i get the error

The following assertion was thrown building Answer(dirty):
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.

This MyApp widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets. A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was: MyApp
state: _MyAppState#e8709
The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was: Answer
dirty
The relevant error-causing widget was:
Answer Answer:file:///E:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/AndroidStudioProjects/quiz/lib/quiz1.dart:27:18

```
class Quiz extends StatelessWidget {
     final List<Map<String, Object>> questions;
     final int questionIndex;
     final Function answerQuestion;

  const Quiz({
      Key? key,
      required this.questions,
      required this.answerQuestion,
      required this.questionIndex,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Question(
          questions[questionIndex]['questionText'].toString(),
        ), //Question
            ...(questions[questionIndex]['answers'] as List<Map<String, Object>>)
              .map((answer) {
                return Answer(
                  ()=> answerQuestion(answer['score']), answer['text'].toString());
        }).toList()
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Question:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Question extends StatelessWidget {
  final String questionText;

  const Question(this.questionText, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Text(
        questionText,
        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 28),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ), //Text
    ); //Container
  }
}
```

Answer:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function selectHandler;
  final String answerText;

  const Answer(this.selectHandler, this.answerText, {Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // use SizedBox for white space instead of Container
    return SizedBox(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: selectHandler(),
        style: ButtonStyle(
            textStyle:
            MaterialStateProperty.all(const TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.green)),
        child: Text(answerText),
      ),
    ); //Container
  }
}
```

Main:

```
void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final _questions = const [
    {
      'questionText' : 'Q1 Who created Flutter?',
      'answers': [
        {'text': 'Facebook', 'score': 0},
        {'text': 'Adobe', 'score': 0},
        {'text': 'Google', 'score': 1},
        {'text': 'Microsoft', 'score': 0},
      ],
    },
  {
    'questionText' : 'Q2 What is Flutter?',
    'answers': [
      {'text': 'Android Development Kit', 'score': 0},
      {'text': 'IOS Development Kit', 'score': 0},
      {'text': 'Web Development Kit', 'score': 0},
      {'text': 'SDK to build IOS, Android, Web and Native Apps', 'score': 1},
    ],
  },
{
    'questionText' : 'Q3 What Programming Language is used in Flutter?',
    'answers': [
      {'text': 'Ruby', 'score': 0},
      {'text': 'Dart', 'score': 1},
      {'text': 'C++', 'score': 0},
      {'text': 'Kotlin', 'score': 0},
    ],
  },
{
    'questionTest' : 'Q4 Who created Cart programming language?',
    'answers' : [
      {'text': 'Lars Bak & Kasper Lund', 'score': 1},
      {'text': 'Brendan Eich', 'score': 0},
      {'text': 'Bjarne Stroustrup', 'score': 0},
      {'text': 'Jeremy Ashkenas', 'score': 0},
    ],
  },
{
    'questionTest' : 'Q5 Which folder do you copy and paste an image into?',
    'answers' : [
      {'text': 'Layout', 'score': 0},
      {'text': 'Resources', 'score': 0},
      {'text': 'Drawable', 'score': 1},
      {'text': 'Java', 'score': 0},
    ],
  },
{
    'questionTest' : 'Q6 What listener is called for the device to register the enter key press?',
    'answers' : [
      {'text': 'OnKeyListener', 'score': 1},
      {'text': 'OnHoverListener', 'score': 0},
      {'text': 'OnContextClickListener', 'score': 0},
      {'text': 'OnClickListener', 'score': 0},
    ],
  },
{
    'questionTest' : 'Q7 Which file do you alter the image displayed by the ImageView in?',
    'answers' : [
      {'text': 'AndroidManifest.xml', 'score': 0},
      {'text': 'Activity_main_xml', 'score': 1},
      {'text': 'Drawable', 'score': 0},
      {'text': 'MainActivity', 'score': 0},
    ],
   },
{
    'questionTest' : 'Q8 What is the correct line of code to get the ID of EditText?',
    'answers' : [
      {'text': 'EditText TextHandler = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nameTextField);', 'score': 1},
      {'text': 'EditText TextHandler = findViewById(R.id.nameTextField);', 'score': 0},
      {'text': 'EditText TextHandler = (EditText)findViewById(nameTextField);', 'score': 0},
      {'text': 'EditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nameTextField);', 'score': 0},
    ],
  },
{
    'questionTest' : 'Q9 What Component should be changed to a name that specific of the components used?',
    'answers' : [
      {'text': 'ID', 'score': 1},
      {'text': 'Text', 'score': 0},
      {'text': 'Content Description', 'score': 0},
      {'text': 'Editable', 'score': 0},
    ],
  },
{
    'questionTest' : 'Q10 Which Android Studio file is most of the app coding done in?',
    'answers' : [
      {'text': 'MainActivity.java', 'score': 1},
      {'text': 'AndroidManifest.xml', 'score': 0},
      {'text': 'Activity_main_xml', 'score': 0},
      {'text': 'MainActivity', 'score': 0},
    ],
  },
];

  var _questionIndex = 0;
  var _totalScore = 0;

  void _resetQuiz() {
    setState(() {
      _questionIndex = 0;
      _totalScore = 0;
    });
  }

  void _answerQuestion(int score) {
    _totalScore += score;

    setState(() {
      _questionIndex = _questionIndex + 1;
    });
    // ignore: avoid_print
    print(_questionIndex);
    if (_questionIndex < _questions.length) {
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print('We have more questions!');
    } else {
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print('No more questions!');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Geeks for Geeks'),
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF00E676),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: _questionIndex < _questions.length
              ? Quiz(
            answerQuestion: _answerQuestion,
            questionIndex: _questionIndex,
            questions: _questions,
          ) //Quiz
              : Result(_totalScore, _resetQuiz)
        ), //Padding
      ), //Scaffold
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    ); //MaterialApp
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what is causing the error, I haven't found anything helpful.

Comment: Please post the code for `Question` and `Answer`.

Comment: have you called `setState` in `_MyAppState` class? please post the code of `_MyAppState`, `Question` and `Answer` wont cause this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the parentheses after `selectHandler` in the `Answer` class:

```dart
class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  final void Function() selectHandler;
  final String answerText;

  const Answer(this.selectHandler, this.answerText, {Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        // Remove the parentheses after selectHandler
        onPressed: selectHandler,
        style: ButtonStyle(
          textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(
            const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
          backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.green),
        ),
        child: Text(answerText),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Using parentheses calls the function, which then calls `setState` during the build method.